# Mostrar líneas que tengan palabras de 4 caracteres | UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, ssh

Sé que tengo que hacer uso de las expresiones simples o regulares, pero la verdad estoy un poco perdido.

**Edit:**
Creo que lo he conseguido hacer, pero no sé si esté en lo correcto, lo que hice fue:

```
grep -i ' .... ' ruta.txt
```

-i: Para que sin importar si sus caracteres son Mayúsculas o Minúsculas mostrarlos.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Dale a [edit] y revisa también [ask] para plantear preguntas que sean útiles

Comment: Listo, ya agregué una solución que encontré, sin embargo; no sé si esté en lo correcto

Comment: deberías poner un [mcve]. Más que nada para ver cómo defines palabras: ¿incluye números? ¿incluye símbolos?